# How to configure rolling serilog-sinks-file to keep the latest log file with the same name

Tags: logging, rollingfileappender, serilog-sinks-file

I like to have an editor open with the latest log file, while my application is running.
I have a 10MB file size limit and Day as the rolling interval.

When the first file, say `log-20210314.log` fills up and serilog starts a new one, the new one has a new name `log-20210314_001.log`, so I need to change which file I'm looking at in my editor.

In contrast, log4j's RollingFileAppender [default rollover strategy](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#DefaultRolloverStrategy) works like this:

| Number of rollovers | Active output target | Archived log files | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | foo.log | - | All logging is going to the initial file. |
| 1 | foo.log | foo-1.log | During the first rollover foo.log is renamed to foo-1.log. A new foo.log file is created and starts being written to. |
| 2 | foo.log | foo-2.log, foo-1.log | During the second rollover foo.log is renamed to foo-2.log. A new foo.log file is created and starts being written to. |
| 3 | foo.log | foo-3.log, foo-2.log, foo-1.log | During the third rollover foo.log is renamed to foo-3.log. A new foo.log file is created and starts being written to. |

In that example, if my editor is open to `foo.log`, I will always see the latest log entries (except for a few seconds when the file is empty immediately after a rollover).

How can I make serilog-sinks-file behave this way?

My config:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": ".\\logs\\log-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 1000000,
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Debug",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] ({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```